# Python3 descriptors don't call __get__ when accessed

Tags: python-3.x, descriptor

Can anyone tell me why when I push test button, `__get__` isnt called? I tried many things but I can't achieve desired behavior:

> when `lt` or `gt` attribute accessed the value of appropriate `QlineEdit` must be returned if checkbox is checked

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout, QRadioButton, QGroupBox, QLineEdit, QCheckBox, QGridLayout, QLabel, QFrame, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIntValidator
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow


class LineDescriptor:
    def __init__(self, row=1, label=None):

        self.label = label
        self.row = row
        self.__name = None

    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        print('get_called')
        if instance is None:
            print('is none')
            return self
        else:
            private_name = '_{0}__{1}'.format(type(instance).__name__,
                                              self.__name)
            check_name = '_{0}__{1}'.format(type(instance).__name__,
                                            self.__name)
            if getattr(instance, check_name).isChecked():
                return getattr(instance, private_name).text()
            else:
                return None


class CheckSelector(QGroupBox):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__dictionary = []
        super(CheckSelector, self).__init__()
        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)

        name = QLabel(name)
        layout.addWidget(name, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.__check = QCheckBox()
        layout.addWidget(self.__check, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        for name, attribute in type(self).__dict__.items():
            if isinstance(attribute, LineDescriptor):
                row = attribute.row
                if attribute.label is not None:
                    label = QLabel(attribute.label)
                    self.layout().addWidget(label, row, 0, 1, 1)
                int_validator = QIntValidator()
                field = QLineEdit()
                field.setValidator(int_validator)
                layout.addWidget(field, row, 1, 1, 1)
                private_name = '_{0}__{1}'.format(type(self).__name__, name)

                setattr(attribute, '_LineDescriptor__name', name)
                setattr(self, name, attribute)
                setattr(self, private_name, field)
                print(attribute)
                print(attribute.__dict__)





class GtCheck(CheckSelector):
    gt = LineDescriptor(1, '>')


class BothCheck(CheckSelector):
    gt = LineDescriptor(1, '>')
    lt = LineDescriptor(2, '<')


def checker():
    print(test.lt)
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

win = QMainWindow()
wid = QFrame()
lay = QVBoxLayout()
test = BothCheck(name='слов')
lay.addWidget(test)
but = QPushButton()
but.clicked.connect(checker)
lay.addWidget(but)
wid.setLayout(lay)
win.setCentralWidget(wid)
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the offending line:

```
setattr(self, name, attribute)
```

Your descriptor is a non-data descriptor (it does not implement `__set__()`).  Thus, this sets the attribute in `self.__dict__`, creating an instance attribute.  Instance attributes take precedence over non-data descriptors.  If you immediately did this on the next line:

```
getattr(self, name)
```

...then the descriptor would not be invoked; it would just fetch `attribute` back out of `self.__dict__` and return it directly.  Since `foo.bar` is *exactly the same* as `getattr(foo, "bar")`, the `foo.bar` syntax won't invoke the descriptor either.

Data descriptors (descriptors which implement `__set__()`) take precedence over instance attributes.  If you changed `LineDescriptor` to implement `__set__()` as well as `__get__()`, it would not exhibit this behavior.  But then you would have to figure out how to implement `__set__()`.  That implementation will depend on what you are trying to accomplish:

1. You could raise `AttributeError` to indicate the descriptor is read-only.  Then you'd have to remove the `setattr()` call, since you can't set a read-only descriptor.
2. You could implement `__set__()` to do the reverse of `__get__()`.  Given the complexity of your `__get__()` method, I'm not entirely sure how to do that.  It'll also change the effect of your `setattr()` call.

If you don't want to change or remove the `setattr()` call, you can always manually set an instance attribute:

```
self.__dict__[name] = attribute
```

This bypasses the data descriptor, and does exactly what the `setattr()` call is currently doing.  However, the attribute probably won't match up with `__get__()`'s return value.  In my opinion, that's poor design, but it's not strictly *wrong*.

Comment: Thank you very much, Kevin.

>In my opinion, that's poor design, but it's not strictly wrong.

This is really important to me: to do it definetely right way.
Thing that I want to achieve is that:
I have filter of objects and it have many such selectors
which I want to respond this way:
they have some attrs
and each of this attrs respond this way:
when selector created - there is one field added to selectors layout for each attr of this kind it have.
when attr accesed: if selectors checkbox checked the value of this attr's field returned.

Which way this may be achieved to be right-designed?

Comment: I'm sorry, but Qt isn't my area of expertise.  Most of your comment is gibberish to me.  What were you trying to do with that `setattr()` call?  What did you hope it would accomplish?

Comment: To grant ability to esily create declarative subclasses.
Subclass have for example:
    class SomeClass(CheckSelector):
          attr1 = LineDescriptor()
          attr2 = LineDescriptor()

What I need: all instances of SomeClass have property with some  behavior. And some steps need to be done at instance.__init__ step for each of such property.

setattr needed only to set property to instance

Comment: "set property to instance" - If I understand you correctly, you don't need to do that.  Descriptors are not *supposed* to be attached to instances.  They are supposed to be attached to classes, which you've already done just by writing `gt = LineDescriptor(1, '>')`.

Comment: But if descriptors not set to instance I have attribute error when try to access such attribute of instance

Comment: I fixed it. Probllem was in Qt - Qt's objects respond differently